# Where am I going wrong in Implicit Differentiation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am considering a system of differential equations
$$\dot{x} = f_1(x, y)\\
\dot{y} = f_2(x,y)$$
where $\dot{x}, \dot{y}$ are derivatives with respect to time $t$. When changing variables into polar coordinations $x \mapsto r\cos(\theta)$, $y \mapsto r\sin(\theta)$, I can derive $\dot{\theta}$ from the relation $\theta = \arctan(\frac{y}{x})$ by the chain rule
\begin{align*}
\dot{\theta} &= \frac{1}{1 + \frac{y^2}{x^2}}\bigg(\frac{x\dot{y}-y\dot{x}}{x^2}\bigg)\\
&= \frac{x\dot{y}-y\dot{x}}{r^2}.
\end{align*}

Which should be correct. However, if I start using implicit differentation on $\tan(\theta) = \frac{y}{x}$, then I get
$$\sec^2(\theta)\dot{\theta} = \frac{x\dot{y}-y\dot{x}}{x^2}$$
where dividing by $\sec^2{\theta}$ gives
$$\dot{\theta} = \frac{x\dot{y}-y\dot{x}}{x^2}\cos^2(\theta).$$
The factor of cosine should be on the denominator. I must be making a dumb mistake, so where am I going wrong? Thank you

Comment: It is all correct. If you replace $x=r\cos\theta$ in your last formula, the cosines cancel out.